# One SQL table with key to two other tables

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have three tables: File, Folder and Security. Security is table, in which I have permissions to files and folders. Id of record in Security table could exist only in one of Folder/File tables. The other table (Folder or File) would not have this id. So I would have situation:

```
Security table holds ids: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Folder table holds ids: 2, 5
File table holds ids: 1, 3, 4
```

How should I set primary and foreign keys, and also Identity, to set up tables like this?
Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be better if you can have 1 table where you can store both files and folders.

This table will have a 'type' column to identify folder/file,etc.